# Need to represent given data in grouped bar chart using chart.js and not able to give name to each bar

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have below data sets

```
const javaData = [
  { name: "NASC-02", type: "Interface", value: 6, bgColor: "red" },
  { name: "NASC-03", type: "Interface", value: 7, bgColor: "green" },
  { name: "NASC-04", type: "Interface", value: 9, bgColor: "blue" },
  { name: "FUNC-01", type: "Function", value: 3, bgColor: "red" },
  { name: "FUNC-02", type: "Function", value: 10, bgColor: "green" },
  { name: "FUNC-03", type: "Function", value: 1, bgColor: "blue" },
];
```

I want to create a grouped bar chart using Chart.js. The x-axis should represent the type of object, which in this case are "Interface" and "Function". Each bar's value and color should be determined by the respective object.

I have successfully created the grouped chart using the provided data. However, I'm facing difficulty in assigning names to each bar. Specifically, I want the name of each bar in the "Interface" group to correspond to the names "NASC-02", "NASC-03", etc., and in the "Function" group to correspond to "FUNC-01", "FUNC-02", etc.

i can change the format of data from backend also in if required

```
    var javaData = {
  "Interface": {
    "NASC-01": 2,
    "NASC-02": 5,
    "NASC-03": 8
  },
  "Function": {
    "FUNC-01": 20,
    "FUNC-02": 25,
    "FUNC-03": 18
  }
};
```

below is the code i have tried using array format data given above graph is coming properly but not able to give name to each bar

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Defect Closure Duration by Type</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="defectChart" width="600" height="300"></canvas>

  <script>
    var javaData = [
      { name: "NASC-02", type: "Interface", value: 6, bgColor: "red" },
      { name: "NASC-03", type: "Interface", value: 7, bgColor: "green" },
      { name: "NASC-04", type: "Interface", value: 9, bgColor: "blue" },
      { name: "FUNC-01", type: "Function", value: 3, bgColor: "red" },
      { name: "FUNC-02", type: "Function", value: 10, bgColor: "green" },
      { name: "FUNC-03", type: "Function", value: 1, bgColor: "blue" },
    ];
    

    // Group data by month
    const groupedData = javaData.reduce((acc, item) => {
      if (!acc[item.type]) {
        acc[item.type] = {};
      }
      acc[item.type][item.name] = item.value;
      return acc;
    }, {});

    // Extract labels and values for each month
    const labels = Object.keys(groupedData);
    const interfaceValues = Object.values(groupedData["Interface"]);
    const functionValues = Object.values(groupedData["Function"]);
    
    const datas = [];

   for (let i = 0; i < interfaceValues.length; i++) {
    datas.push([interfaceValues[i], functionValues[i]]);
   }

const dataset = datas.map((data, index) => {
    return {
        data: data,
        backgroundColor: index === 0 ? 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)' : 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        borderColor: index === 0 ? 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)' : 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        borderWidth: 1
    };
});

    var ctx = document.getElementById("defectChart").getContext("2d");
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: dataset
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the screen the way i need bar name
[image]

Comment: You need different names for the columns on each group. Certainly not the most common scenario on chart.js samples out there. Have you seen this post: [ChartJS Separate Labels for each dataset/independent datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63695328/chartjs-separate-labels-for-each-dataset-independent-datasets)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky as each group/category has its dataset and from the Chart.JS sample/design with the bar/dataset will have multiple categories.

1. In each dataset, you can provide the `datalabels` property to set the position of the datalabels shown in each bar. For more information and configuration, you can refer to [Positioning | chartjs-plugin-datalabels documentation](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/positioning.html).

```js
const dataset = datas.map((data, index) => {
  return {
    data: data,
    backgroundColor:
      index === 0 ? 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)' : 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
    borderColor:
      index === 0 ? 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)' : 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
    borderWidth: 1,
    datalabels: {
      align: 'top',
      anchor: 'end',
    },
  };
});
```

2. Implement a function to get the `name` by the position. You need to ensure that the `javaData` is sorted by `type` for correctness. The formula:

```js
function getBarLabelName(dataIndex, datasetIndex) {
  return javaData[2 * dataIndex + dataIndex + datasetIndex].name;
}
```

Add the `datalabels` object in the `plugins` for displaying the label in each bar.

```js
plugins: {
  ...,
  datalabels: {
    color: 'black', // Set the color of the data labels
    font: {
      weight: 'bold',
    },
    formatter: function (value, context) {
      return getBarLabelName(context.dataIndex, context.datasetIndex);
    },
  }
}
```

Don't forget to register the `ChartDataLabels` plugin.

```js
new Chart(ctx, {
  ...,
  plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
});
```

3. (Optional) If you want to customize the tooltip to show the label name of each bar when hover:

```js
plugins: {
  ...,
  tooltip: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function (context) {
        let label = getBarLabelName(
          context.dataIndex,
          context.datasetIndex
        );

        label += ': ';
        label += context.parsed.y;

        return label;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

4. Notice that your `yAxes` configuration with an array `[]`. It was the old configuration for Chart.js version 2.X. For the version 4, it should be:

```js
options: {
  scales: {
    y: {
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
      },
      max: Math.max(...javaData.map((x) => x.value)) + 2,
    }
  }
}
```

You may face that the data label is overflown when the value is the max value of the y-axis. In this case, you need to increase the `max` value of the y-axis.

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-kpr1lw?file=index.html)

[image]